# How to unselect checkbox in chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, wicket

in my wicket application I have 3 checkbox in form:

```
        add(new CheckBox("1").setOutputMarkupId(true));
        add(new CheckBox("2").setOutputMarkupId(true));
        add(new CheckBox("3").setOutputMarkupId(true));
```

form also contain behavior which unselect checboxes

```
        add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                List<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>();

                if (target.getLastFocusedElementId() != null) {
                    if (target.getLastFocusedElementId().equals("1")) {
                        components.add(get("2"));
                        components.add(get("3"));
                    } else if (target.getLastFocusedElementId().equals("2")) {
                        components.add(get("1"));
                    } else if (target.getLastFocusedElementId().equals("3")) {
                        components.add(get("1"));
                    }
                    for (Component component : components) {
                        component.setDefaultModelObject(null);
                        target.add(component);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

this works good on mozilla browser but in chrome this doesnt work. How I can improve  to work this on chrome too ?

---

**UPDATE**

problem is in:

```
target.getLastFocusedElementId()
```

in mozilla this return what I want but in chrome it always return null but I dont know wh

---

**UPDATE 2**

google chrome has bug in focus element:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1383&can=1&q=window.focus%20type%3aBug&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner

so I need to do this in other way

Comment: According to `AjaxRequestTarget`'s [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.7/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.java#AjaxRequestTarget.getLastFocusedElementId%28%29), looks like `getLastFocusedElementId()` relies on the value of a `Wicket-FocusedElementId` header in the request. Did you check the header is there?

Comment: IDs must start with a letter.

Comment: Without knowing much about what you want to achieve, I see there's something strange in the code you posted. Firing an Ajax request just to uncheck some checkboxes might be a bit of an overkill, why not just code this behavior client-side? Also, do you really need to check which checkbox was last _focused_? Which component is the behavior attached to? If you put a little more context on what you're trying to achieve, it'd be easier to help you.

Comment: ok context: I have 2 check box on off. They cant be check together so when client check on, off should uncheckeck and vice versa.

Comment: I'd implement this completely client-side, with a server side validation at submit time just for those users without JS enabled. If you really want to do it server side, why not attaching different behaviors for every checkbox?

Comment: how ? main requirement of client is to AUTOMATIC uncheck checkboxes, because this application is using on mobile where is sometimes hard to check or uncheck all check boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fix chrome bug with focus when I add this behavior to checkboxes:

```
public class DefaultFocusBehavior extends AjaxEventBehavior {

public DefaultFocusBehavior(String event) {
    super(event);
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

private Component component;

@Override
protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    target.appendJavaScript(("document.getElementById('" + component.getMarkupId() + "').blur();"
            + "document.getElementById('" + component.getMarkupId() + "').focus();"));

}

protected void onBind() {
    this.component = getComponent();
    component.setOutputMarkupId(true);
}
```

}

so now my code is working on chrome too

Answer (score 1):

### Client-sided solution (Javascript)

You could save an Ajax call and gain responsiveness by coding that behavior client-side. In the simplest of the scenarios, if you can give those checkboxes a fixed "id" attribute, you could use `Component.setMarkupId()` to force an `id` value for the checks (make sure it is unique in the DOM):

**Java**

```
add(new CheckBox("1").setOutputMarkupId(true).setMarkupId("check1");
add(new CheckBox("2").setOutputMarkupId(true).setMarkupId("check2");
add(new CheckBox("3").setOutputMarkupId(true).setMarkupId("check3");
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" wicket:id="1" onclick="uncheck(this,1)"/>
<input type="checkbox" wicket:id="2" onclick="uncheck(this,2)"/>
<input type="checkbox" wicket:id="3" onclick="uncheck(this,3)"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function uncheck(comp, idx){
   if (comp.checked) { 
       if (idx == 1){
           document.getElementById("check2").checked = false;
           document.getElementById("check3").checked = false;
       }
       else if (idx == 2 || idx == 3){
           document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;             
       } 
   }
}     ​
```

---

### Java only solution (Ajax)

If you really want to do this server-side, it would make sense to also propagate the values server side (instead of relying on which component was last focused), for instance with `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`.

```
        final CheckBox c1 = new CheckBox("on");
        final CheckBox c2 = new CheckBox("off");
        c1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        c2.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        c1.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            protected void onUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(c1.getModelObject())) {
                    c2.setModelObject(Boolean.FALSE);
                    target.add(c2);
                }
            }
        });

        c2.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            protected void onUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(c2.getModelObject())) {
                    c1.setModelObject(Boolean.FALSE);
                    target.add(c1);
                }
            }
        });

        add(c1);
        add(c2);
```

If this constraint is important for the integrity of your data model, you should also implement it in a `FormValidator` so that invalid input never reaches the `Form`'s `Model`s. Users without JS enabled or just fiddling with the DOM could bypass it (the same would apply if using an Ajax Behavior).

Comment: hm nice example. I dont use this because I dont know js. I just know java and wicket

Comment: Added an example on how to do it with Ajax (no JS-coding involved). However, I'd go for the client-sided solution; including a JS function in a page is quite easy, and you can even do it from Wicket (see `HeaderContributor`s)

Comment: nice example but I try it and it doesnt work too !!. First your code is not compiled and you are using deprecated method like   target.addComponent(c1);. Secondly when I correct your code doesnt work on chrome too

Comment: How come it's not working on Chrome? Have you tried debugging the Ajax  behaviors, or looking in the ajax debug console? Also, the code I posted is just a suggestion, and apart from obvious compilation errors, it _has_ to be tailored to your specific needs (for instance, we don't know what the model objects for your `CheckBox`s are).

Comment: because Chrome sucks :) and I dont have time to trying debug it and how I posted below I have my own solution which works